# Switch between Dosbox and Linux

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

When playing old dos games on DosBox in Linux (Mint 20), I get locked in and cannot find any shortcuts to switch over to Xfce desktop or running applications in Linux.

In Windows you can easily do this with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> keys.

Comment: Discovered that Ctrl+F10 in DOSBox - capture/release mouse, helped.

Answer (score 2):

My dosbox man page (`man dosbox`) tells me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> captures/releases the mouse. And that they can be changed in the keymapper (i.e., by running `dosbox -startmapper`).